# Possibility of sharing a List Container among two different projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am currently facing a problem and I cant seem to explain it. In my C# solution I have three projects A,B and C. Both A and B reference project C which contains a static List container. Now when project A adds to the container surprisingly project B cant find the content in the container. Any suggestions why this is happening ?

Comment: Please post your code in here

Comment: It's not clear exactly what *processes* we're talking about. Are A and B separate applications, running as separate processes? It's not like static variables are shared *globally* - they're only within a single AppDomain, within a single process.

Comment: Are they separate executables?  Even if they share common code in the solution, they will be in different processes when run.

Comment: Yes the two projects are different exe files thus different processes

Comment: So they are two different processes and thus I believe they cant share the container

Comment: @MistyD Correct, they won't share data just by marking the class and/or property as static.  But there are ways to share data between two processes; it just takes more dev effort.  See D Stanley's answer for some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` items are only shared *within the same AppDomain*.  If A and B run in separate spaces (two different web sites, console apps, WinForms, whatever) they will not share the same memory space.

If you need to share data between two different processes you need to come up with a different way to do that.  some options are:

- Use a database
- Use files
- Create a web service that *hosts* the shared data
- Create a windows service that hosts the data

Each have their pros/cons for dev time/complexiity/maintainability/etc.

<strike>If they are two different web sites you can set them to use the same AppPool and they *may* share static variables (though I haven't ever tried it).</strike>

EDIT: based on further research two web apps will have different AppDomains even if they share an AppPool. (An AppPool can host multiple independent AppDomains).

Comment: More options: Named pipes, .net remoting, message queues

Comment: Yep, there's a hundred ways to skin that cat.